# Find the inverse of the following piecewise defined function

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Find the inverse of $f$ if $f(x)=$
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2-x}, &\text{for $x<0$}\\ 
1-x^2, &\text{for $x \ge 0$} \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

**My effort**

For  $y=\sqrt{2-x}$ ,we find 
\begin{array}{c}
y=\sqrt{2-x} \\
y^2=2-x  &\text{(I can do this since $\sqrt{2-x}>0$ ,for $x<0$)} \\
x=2-y^2
\end{array}

So for this piece of function we have $f^{-1}(x)=2-x^2$ for $x>\sqrt{2}$ since this the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{2-x}$ for $x<0$.

Now, for the second part of the function we have 
\begin{array}{c}
y=1-x^2 \\
x^2=1-y \\
x=\sqrt{1-y} ,&\text{since $x\ge 0 $}
\end{array}

So for this latter part we have $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$ which has domain $(-\inf,1]$ .

so our piecewise defined function for $f^{-1}$ is
\begin{array}{c}
2-x^2 , &\text{for $x> \sqrt{2} $} \\
\sqrt{1-x}, &\text{ for $x\le1$} \\
\end{array}

> **Question**
>
> Is my effort correct ?Can it be tightened up in some parts ?

Comment: It is fine. At the very end we want "for $x\le 1$".  As to tightening up, it is good and clear now.

Comment: @AndrèNicolas Right,thanks sir for your disponibility.